# Get prefixMap from Fuseki

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

I have java app that works with jena tdb and it works fine. Now i migrated to Fuseki and when i want to get the Prefixes i am getting empty List.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
model.setNsPrefixes(resultSet.getResourceModel().getNsPrefixMap());
```

This is empty:

> resultSet.getResourceModel().getNsPrefixMap()

When i add prefixes like this in the code instead of setting the map it works fine:

```
model.setNsPrefix("Hello", "http://Hello#");
```

But i want to get all the prefixes and not to specify them in the code. So i found something like this:

```
 String str = "http://localhost:3030/tdb2-database/data";
 Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel(str);
```

Like this i am getting all the prefixes but it build the model in wrong way with adding nested objects and etc.

My question is how to get the prefixes like in local Jena with getNsPrefixMap

Answer (score 2):

Prefixes are for presentation and don't affect the results.
Prefixes are not part of the SPARQL result set.

You can add them locally if you want to for local presentation. One place that is common to take them from is the query used for the result set. The query object has a prologue which has the prefixes in it.